# CSS making tables have moveable columns

Tags: css

I'm currently trying to make a table with css but when I'm trying to make the columns be able to be moved it doesn't seem like there is a way to do that with css by itself. I've seen tabulator as an option but I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do this than install a library

Answer (score 0):

For this type of interaction you need some javascript, not css, there is no other way to move columns from html tables.

Several libraries indeed offer this option, including [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) or, as you mentioned, [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/).